# Show Text and number in a Pivot Table Values Area

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a spreadsheet that I'm trying to convert to a pivot table. My issue is the Data(Value) section is a range of numbers (0-10) and text (intermittent, frequent, often). How can I accommodate both into my table?

sample data set (highlighted column):

[image]

http://govega.com/1.png

expected pivot table result:

[image]

Comment: Show a data sample of the source data and show the expected result, mocked up manually. Edit your question to do that. Then post a comment.

Comment: @teylyn Please see updates.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot tables cannot show text in the values area. Values are always aggregated. Text can be counted, but not displayed as is.

It's a shame you didn't include column headers in the data. What you want to achieve might be possible with a regular table and formulas, but with such vague info about the data structure, it's hard to tell. It looks like you have months across the second screenshot, so there must me some date column in the source data.

Please simplify the data for an example. Leave out columns that are not relevant, but please include data that is needed to arrive at the desired result. A few rows will suffice. What makes up the rows in the second screenshot? Are these people? Is it conceivable that any one cell in the grid will have values from two or more source data rows?

Please edit your question with these details and then I'll tidy up this answer.

Post a comment when you're done.